# Bootstrap modal with iframe full screen inside modal body

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a full screen modal with an embedded website or iframe. However, I am having issues with the iframe inside `<div class="modal-body">`. The modal is overlayed and it just shows the page. It's missing its button controls such as: `<div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>` and title: `<h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>`  However, I want to have a button that closes the modal. So that you can continue browsing the original page instead of pressing back button on the browser.

[image]

So when the user is finished viewing the iframe inside a modal he can go back to the original page. With the help of the close button and modal closes itself.

[image]

```js
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">');
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

/*modal fullscreen */

.modal.modal-fullscreen {
  /* Maximize the main wrappers on the screen */
  /* Make the parent wrapper of the modal box a full-width block */
  /* Remove borders and effects on the content */
  /**
  * /!\ By using this feature, you force the header and footer to be placed
  * in an absolute position. You must handle by yourself the margin of the
  * content.
  */
}
.modal.modal-fullscreen .modal-dialog,
.modal.modal-fullscreen .modal-content {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.modal.modal-fullscreen .modal-dialog {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  animation-duration:0.6s;
}
.modal.modal-fullscreen .modal-content {
  border: none;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inherit;
  -moz-box-shadow: inherit;
  -o-box-shadow: inherit;
  box-shadow: inherit;
  /* change bg color below */
 /* background:#1abc9c; */
}
.modal.modal-fullscreen.force-fullscreen {
  /* Remove the padding inside the body */
}
.modal.modal-fullscreen.force-fullscreen .modal-body {
  padding: 0;
}
.modal.modal-fullscreen.force-fullscreen .modal-header,
.modal.modal-fullscreen.force-fullscreen .modal-footer {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
.modal.modal-fullscreen.force-fullscreen .modal-header {
  top: 0;
}
.modal.modal-fullscreen.force-fullscreen .modal-footer {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">

        <div class="text-center">
             <h1 class="">Welcomeo</h1>

            <p class="lead">Have a look at this website!</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalFullscreen" contenteditable="false">Open Fullscreen Modal</button>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- /.container -->
<div class="modal fade modal-fullscreen  footer-to-bottom" id="myModalFullscreen" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog animated zoomInLeft">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
             <iframe src="https://www.android.com" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
    Your browser doesn't support iframes
</iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the inline style of the `z-index` being too high blocked it. Your `modal-title` and `modal-footer` doesn't really go away.

I transferred your code to a codepen so it's easier to play around with it and test it on "fullscreen" but it should work there. Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QqwLzM)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

it try help full

```js
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">');
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

/*modal fullscreen */

.modal.modal-fullscreen {
  /* Maximize the main wrappers on the screen */
  /* Make the parent wrapper of the modal box a full-width block */
  /* Remove borders and effects on the content */
  /**
  * /!\ By using this feature, you force the header and footer to be placed
  * in an absolute position. You must handle by yourself the margin of the
  * content.
  */
}
.modal.modal-fullscreen .modal-dialog,
.modal.modal-fullscreen .modal-content {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.modal.modal-fullscreen .modal-dialog {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  animation-duration:0.6s;
}
.modal.modal-fullscreen .modal-content {
  border: none;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inherit;
  -moz-box-shadow: inherit;
  -o-box-shadow: inherit;
  box-shadow: inherit;
  /* change bg color below */
 /* background:#1abc9c; */
}
.modal.modal-fullscreen.force-fullscreen {
  /* Remove the padding inside the body */
}
.modal.modal-fullscreen.force-fullscreen .modal-body {
  padding: 0;
}
.modal.modal-fullscreen.force-fullscreen .modal-header,
.modal.modal-fullscreen.force-fullscreen .modal-footer {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
.modal.modal-fullscreen.force-fullscreen .modal-header {
  top: 0;
}
.modal.modal-fullscreen.force-fullscreen .modal-footer {
  bottom: 0;
}

.close {
    float: right;
    font-size: 81px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
    opacity: .2;
    right: 50%;
    position: relative;
    background: #000 !important;
    z-index: 1111111;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">

        <div class="text-center">
             <h1 class="">Welcomeo</h1>

            <p class="lead">Have a look at this website!</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalFullscreen" contenteditable="false">Open Fullscreen Modal</button>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- /.container -->
<div class="modal fade modal-fullscreen  footer-to-bottom" id="myModalFullscreen" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog animated zoomInLeft">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
             <iframe src="https://www.android.com" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
    Your browser doesn't support iframes
</iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```